# How to Throw an Exception in OnNext using RxJava/RxAndroid

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I am using Retrofit for the network call in my android app. Now if the response if something wrong (maybe wrong data), I do not want the onComplete to be executed. Please see the code snippet,

```
restClient.getService().getProjectDetail(projectId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Project>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Project> value) {
                        /*Something wrong in the data and I would like to execute onError*/
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        handleError(e, 0, "");
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your end-consumer can crash, the straightforward way is to catch that exception and delegate to `onError`:

```
.subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Project>>() {
    @Override
    public void onNext(List<Project> value) {
        try {
            // something that can crash
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // tell the upstream we can't accept any more data
            dispose();
            // do the error handling
            onError(ex);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        handleError(e, 0, "");
        hideProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        hideProgressDialog();
    }
});
```

On a side note, RxJava does [pretty much this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/operators/flowable/FlowableMap.java#L64) in its own operators when dealing with potentially failing user functions: try-catch, [cancel the source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/subscribers/BasicFuseableSubscriber.java#L110) and signal through `onError`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, it goes to onError, but it also goes to onComplete. How can I stop calling onComplete.

Comment: Are you sure it goes to onComplete when the onNext fails?

Comment: Yes, I debugged that.

Comment: Your source must be something hand crafted that ignores cancellation before it emits a terminal event. You can protect against this by  `if (!isDisposed()) hideProgressDialog();` in `onComplete`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatMap. ex:

```
restClient.getService().getProjectDetail(projectId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .flatMap(new Function<Integer, Observable<List<Project>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<List<Project>> apply(List<Project> x) {
                        if(validate(x)){
                            return Observable.error(new Exception("Response is invalid"));
                        }else {
                          return   Observable.just(x);
                        }
                    }

                    public boolean validate(List<Project> x){
                        return x.size()==0;
                    }
                })
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<List<Project>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<Project> value) {
                        /*Something wrong in the data and I would like to execute onError*/
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        handleError(e, 0, "");
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });
```

example other:

```
Observable.just(1)
                .flatMap(new Function<Integer, Observable<Integer>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<Integer> apply(Integer x) {
                        if(validate(x)){
                            return Observable.error(new Exception("Response is invalid"));
                        }else {
                          return   Observable.just(x);
                        }

                    }

                    public boolean validate(Integer x){
                        return x==1;
                    }
                })
                .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Integer integer) {
                        Log.d("flatMap", "onNext: " + integer.toString());
                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are questioning the basic behaviour of rx-java. if you want call hideProgressDialog only once. you should delete that from onError. the sequence must destroy after problem.

but if you want to get other items in onNext and avoid onError you can use this method on your observable chain:`onErrorResumeNext`

```
restClient.getService().getProjectDetail(projectId).onErrorResumeNext(/*Func1*/)
```

consider this method will emit `List<Project>` in onNext instead of onError. and onComplete would not call

as long as you use retrofit the onNext only will invoke one times. so the better solution is the first one